# Failed to execute MI command -exec-run

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gcc, gdb, gnu

I am using eclipse ide. First i got

> Cannot run program ".gdb": Launching failed

error but i get rid of this after put the path of `arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe`

but now i get this error.

Error in final launch sequence:

> Failed to execute MI command:
>
> -exec-run

Error message from debugger back end:

> Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".

Failed to execute MI command:

> -exec-run

Error message from debugger back end:

> Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".
>
> Don't know how to run.  Try "help target".

What should i do?